# Getting data from <tbody> using requests and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

To learn using `beautifulsoup4` better, I am trying to get some data from https://semlar.com/rivenprices/artax (of course I am and will use the data ONLY for learning purposes, to avoid any potential legal issues. All the data I am posting here is available for everyone using the 'inspect' browser feature).

This site shows average prices of special mods in the game called Warframe, but that's besides the point. I would like to write an app that takes the mod name (for example Artax, Lanka etc.) from the user and prints the "Avg Price" and "Dispo" values.

Here is link to a small portion of the table I would like to get data off:
https://imggmi.com/full/2018/5/28/daa550ff5f042bb80ab0ecdd980a3935-full.png.html

I did apps like this before, but here I have encountered a problem - the names of weapons, prices and 'dispositions' seem to be hidden under the `tbody` tag, which is empty when I search the data with `bs4`.

My program so far:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = requests.get('https://semlar.com/rivenprices/artax').text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find(class_='table')
```

In this case, `data` is:

```
<table class="table" id="riven-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Riven Name</th>
<th class="price-avg">Avg Price</th>
<th class="riven-disposition">Dispo</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you see, the `<tbody>` tag is empty, but when you inspect any element from the table in your browser, it seems to be just inside this tag, under `<tbody><tr><td>` - here is a screenshot showing a part of the inspected code:

https://imggmi.com/full/2018/5/28/0619e4d1944c0291bfa70a30678b3f51-full.png.html

Answer (score 0):

You know what they say: *If they throw you out the door, come back through the window.*

I managed to do the thing I wanted in very different way, which I would call "brute-force-non-safe-and-reliable-at-all" way. The program:

1. Opens the web browser, waits fixed time till the webpage loads, automatically presses *Ctrl+A*, waits a moment again, presses *Ctrl+C* and closes the browser (or browser card if there are many). Here I used the `webbrowser`, `time` and `pywinauto` modules.
2. Pastes the clipboard to `rawdata.txt` file. I did this just to make sure I don't mess up my testing while I write and run the code over and over by randomly copying some text. I used `pyperclip` to do this. The file is later opened and content is formatted to create a dictionary in form `{'weapon_name': ['mod_price', 'disposition'], 'next_weapon_name: [...], ...}`.
3. At last the program asks user of weapon name he wants to check and it provides him with data from the dictionary. Then he can rerun the loop again to ask about other gun or just end the program.

Code:

```
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
import pywinauto.keyboard as pkbd
import pyperclip

url = 'https://semlar.com/rivenprices/lanka'


def greet():
    print("This app will get data from {}".format(url))
    print("You will be able to check riven mod price and disposition for desired weapon.")


def open_browser_get_to_clipboard():
    webbrowser.open(url)
    sleep(10)
    pkbd.SendKeys('^a')
    sleep(2)
    pkbd.SendKeys('^c')
    sleep(1)
    pkbd.SendKeys('%{F4}')


def write_to_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'w+') as fin:
        fin.write(pyperclip.paste())


def format_data_from_file(fname):
    riven_database = dict()
    with open(fname, 'r') as fout:
        data = fout.read().split('\n')
        start_ind = data.index('Riven Name\tAvg Price\tDispo')
        formatted_data = data[start_ind + 1:]
        formatted_data = list(filter(None, formatted_data))

        for item in formatted_data:
            temp = item.split('\t')
            riven_database.update({temp[0]: [temp[1], temp[2]]})

        return riven_database


def ask_user_and_check(riven_dict):
    print("Which weapon would you like to look up for?")
    while True:
        decision = input(">>> ")
        if decision.upper() not in riven_dict.keys():
            print("Weapon name not found. Try again.")
            decision = input(">>> ")
        else:
            print("You have picked {} weapon to check.".format(decision.upper()))
            break

    return decision.upper()


def print_output(decision, riven_dict):
    print("Name of the weapon: {}".format(decision))
    print("Average riven mod price: {} platinum".format(riven_dict[decision][0]))
    print("Riven disposition of picked weapon: {}".format(riven_dict[decision][1]))


def quit_or_loop_again():
    print("Do you want to search again or quit?")
    print("To search again input any character, to quit input [x] or [X].")
    decision = input(">>> ")
    if decision in ['x', 'X']:
        print('Good bye.')
    else:
        main()


def main():
    greet()
    open_browser_get_to_clipboard()
    write_to_file('rawdata.txt')
    riven_database = format_data_from_file('rawdata.txt')
    decision = ask_user_and_check(riven_database)
    print_output(decision, riven_database)
    quit_or_loop_again()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think I will just leave it here, maybe somebody will take something out of it, which I doubt considering how this all works. It's surely not pretty and will fail if the user does any action like closing the browser or changing browser tab. Still it took me some work and I'm kinda proud I did it even in such a way. I used modules that were really interesting and learned new things along the way, which is this all about, I guess.